# Databases' names not appearing

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm following a tutorial on Flask Web Development.
I'm trying to build a database, and this is what I should get

```
>>> Role.query.all()
[<Role u'Administrator'>, <Role u'User'>]
>>> User.query.all()
[<User u'john'>, <User u'susan'>, <User u'david'>]
```

but when I try, I don't have the names but this:

```
>>> Role.query.all()
[<hello.Role object at 0x000001F135C1EBE0>, <hello.Role object at 0x000001F135C345F8>]
>>> User.query.all()
[<hello.User object at 0x000001F135C34C50>, <hello.User object at 0x000001F135C34CF8>, <hello.User object at 0x000001F135C34DA0>]
```

I've tried to do all the procedure more times to check if I did something different from the tutorial, but the result is still the same. Do you know what's the cause and how can I overcome it?
Thanks in advance for helping this newbie.

Comment: Your `Role` class lacks [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method.

Answer (score 0):

In the class you define,as Role or User, you should rewrite `__repr__` function.

```
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "roles"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))

    # the name is the output result you want to get.
    # so, in your class, you define it and in the under function, you also define it.
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role `{}`>'.format(self.name)
```

Comment: In the tutorial the code for that was return '<Role %r>' % self.name, I've tried your version too but it still doesn't work. Thanks anyway